# Default variable that is passed to views

Tags: php, templates, variables, cakephp

Very simple CakePHP question.

I know you can pass data with `$this->set()` in controller, and I know data exists in `$this->request->data`.

Does CakePHP pass the `request->data` to a named variable that can be called in the view automatically? Or, do I always have to do `$this->set('variable', 'data')` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Request data is accessible automatically in the view without the need to set it as a variable:

```
$this->request->data(...
```

Fore example ([accessing POST data](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#accessing-post-data)):

```
$this->request->data['MyModel']['title'];
```

You can just `debug($this->request->data());` in your View to see what's available to you.

Comment: Is accessing the request data directly considered good practice?

Comment: I don't see why it wouldn't be.  Someone feel free to correct me if I'm wrong.  Seems better practice than adding variables for no other reason that adding variables.